# Cookies issue on localhost with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, localhost

I want to do authentication with cookies on my localhost. I am trying to use the response cookie from one api as a request cookie in another api. the incoming response cookie comes correctly but the request cookie goes wrong.

I am making a login request from the client side like this.

```
const onSubmit = async (values, actions) => {

  const apiUrl = ${import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT}/users/login;

    setLoader(true)

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, JSON.stringify(values), {
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        });

        if ((response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300)) {
            actions.resetForm();
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.response);
    } finally {
        setLoader(false)
    }

};
```

and api side;

```
user.post("/login", async (req, res) => { 

try { const {usernameEmail, password} = req.body;

const user = await UserModel.findOne({
        $or: [
            {username: usernameEmail},
            {email: usernameEmail},
        ]
    })

    if (!user) {
        console.error("user not found.")
        return res
            .status(401)
            .json({error: "User not found."})

    }

    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
        console.error("wrong password.")
        return res
            .status(401)
            .json({error: "Wrong username/email or password"})
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({
        _id: user._id,
        role:user.role
    }, process.env.JWT_PRIVKEY, {expiresIn: "1h"});

    res.cookie(process.env.USER_COOKIE, token, {httpOnly: false, secure: false, sameSite: "none"});

    return res
        .status(200)
        .json({message: "login success."})

} catch (e) {
    res
        .status(500)
        .json({error: `internal server error, ${e}`});
}
})
```

the incoming cookie is this:

{"Response cookies": {"415a9787d1c9c83cad7249d44aa987d4804dd6b22c27714c404c40a5ee70d48c": {"path": "/","samesite": "None","value": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NWRlNmNiYzRiZGY4ZjRiMWEwYjEzMmYiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDkzOTg5NTMsImV4cCI6MTcwOTQwMjU1M30.kDi0sSxNO6dr2-m9RGfWDOW87ek5dEl6b-J-g6Nlphc"}}}

There is no error here. But then...

```
const fetchUserData = async () => {


const apiUrl = ${import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT}/users/verify;  



try {
        const response = await axios(apiUrl,{},{
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: "include",
        });

        if ((response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300)) {
            console.log(response.data);
            setIsAuthorize(true);
        }

        console.log(response)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.response)
    }
}
```

when I try to make a request from here, the request cookie looks like this and this is not the incoming cookie, the request goes wrong

{ "Request cookies": { "{c0f94d00-d374-4ba9-a5eb-363f33ff13b6}": "value" } }

This works fine when I do it with postman. I have a problem with the browser, there are no errors in the CORS settings.

api side .env

```
USER_COOKIE=415a9787d1c9c83cad7249d44aa987d4804dd6b22c27714c404c40a5ee70d48c
JWT_PRIVKEY=fb44265e9f2d4d26e435194acea0e40d08f6b36cdcd1d24eb2f6e07de032572f
```

Comment: So you wrote some code that doesn't behave as you expect. What do you hope to get from stack overflow if you don't share your code?

Comment: You're right. I tried to add the codes and failed. I updated it now

Comment: I’d be careful with those private keys being shared. Rotate them now

Comment: these are the operations I did on localhost, what could be the problem? just out of curiosity, I'm a student